# How to set vite.config.js base public path?

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm trying to set a **base url** for both my dev and prod environments, but `vitejs` configs are not resolved.

According to [vitejs](https://vitejs.dev/config/)  , you can set the base public path when served in development or production, in your config options.

> When running vite from the command line, Vite will automatically try to resolve a config file named vite.config.js inside project root.

The issue is that my application requests don't go through `'http://localhost:8080/'`, but are still appended to the default serving port `http://localhost:3000/`.

My current configs are bellow:

```
// vite.config.js
export default {
  base: 'http://localhost:8080/'
}
```

```
// packages.json
{
  "name": "vue3ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "vue": "^3.0.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.11",
    "vite": "^1.0.0-rc.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you really just trying to change the port? That's the only change I see in the `base` config.

Comment: I'm trying to make the vite port config work, but yes. When it works I'll add a conditional statement to set a port for dev and `/` for prod.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<s>Not totally clear to me but</s> I will try to give you an answer to achieve what you want.

> I'm trying to set a base url for both my dev and prod environments

**Edit:** I read again you question, and I think you are looking for the point **C** on this answer.

**Changes should be made in `vite.config.js`**

**A)** You are looking to change the running port from `3000` to `8080`, adjust `server.port`

```
server: {
  port: '8080'
}
```

**B)** But if you are looking to run on `localhost:3000` and forward requests to `localhost:8080` then you have to adjust `server.proxy`

```
server: {
    proxy: {
      '/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080/'
      },

      '/admin': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8081/'
      }
    }
  }
```

> example:
>
> - `'/'`: will proxy all requests to `localhost:8080`
> - `'/admin'`: will proxy only requests that have as endpoint `/admin` to `http://localhost:8081`

**C)** Changing base path depending on dev or prod environment

`.env` file :

```
// .env
 
// Running locally
APP_ENV=local
// you change port of local/dev here to :8000
// do not forget to adjust `server.port`
ASSET_URL=http://localhost:3000
 
// Running production build
APP_ENV=production
ASSET_URL=https://your-prod-asset-domain.com
```

`vite.config.js`:

```
const ASSET_URL = process.env.ASSET_URL || '';

export default { 
  base: `${ASSET_URL}/dist/`,

  [...]
}
```

If it's not what you are looking for, please be more precise and I will edit my answer.

For more information, head to the official doc at https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-options

Comment: I tried applying your example to change `localhost:3000` to `api.domain.com` but it does not work. executing npm dev or yarn dev would still show on terminal `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: @Shulz without more details I cannot help you, but from what you are saying, of course, the `dev` command still launch the local server, in this answer I am only talking about  **redirecting by the proxy some url segments configured in the config file.** This config `server: {  proxy: { '/api': { target: 'https://api.domain.com'  }` will still show you localhost, but if you follow the request of `localhost:3000/api`, it's sent to `api.domain.com`.

Answer (score 4):

I think I understand what TC wants to solve.
He has 1 **build** for **dev** and **prod** envs.

But it depends on envs, he has a different base path.

**Answer:**
https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#advanced-base-options
At the moment it is an experimental feature

```js
experimental: {
  renderBuiltUrl(filename: string, { hostType }: { hostType: 'js' | 'css' | 'html' }) {
    if (['js', 'css'].includes(hostType)) {
      return { runtime: `window.__getFile(${JSON.stringify(filename)})` }
    } else {
      return { relative: true }
    }
  }
}
```

and create global function

```js
window.__getFile = function(file){
  if (window.location.host.includes('dev')) {
    return `http://cdn.dev/${file}`
  }
  return `http://cdn.prod/${file}`
}
```

P.s. Sorry. I can't find any example with port