# How to configure Vite dev server for running through a port proxy path?

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm trying to use Vite dev server in a cloud-based development environment where I *can* serve on and connect to ports, but need to access them through a proxy path.

Instead of `http://localhost:3000/index.html` I would visit e.g. `https://my.cool.example.com/proxy/3000/index.html`. Under the hood, the cloud service translates the URL and proxies the connection through: So to Vite it looks like I'm just requesting `/index.html`.

...But the various configs I've tried in `vite.config.js` haven't got this working properly yet:

- Setting `base` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69041080/13352657) complains "The server is configured with a public base URL of /proxy/3000/"
- Several other unsuccessful experiments with `server.base`, `proxy`, `publicPath` and similar

How can I tell Vite that the client and assets should set a path prefix on requests, but the server can serve from root?

Answer (score 1):

My solution to fix this problem was to make many stuff on reverse proxy inside nginx on **filename.conf** file inside your domain conf you need to set something like that

```
 location /admin {
        include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass        https://your-service:8081;
    }

    location ^~ /@vite {
        include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass            https://your-service:8081;
    }
    location /__vite_ping {
        include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass        https://your-service:8081;
    }
    location /src {
        include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass        https://your-service:8081;
    }
    location /node_modules {
        include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass        https://your-service:8081;
    }
```

**proxy.conf** file look in this way

```
xy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

Inside of your **vite.config** you must do something like that

```
server: {
    https: true, 
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 8081,
    secure: false,
    strictPort: true,
    hmr: {
      port: 8081,
      host: "localhost",
    }, 
  },
```

the important think was to the hrm value to overwrite host and the port need to be the same that you are exposing on docker

service vaues of **docker-compose.yml**

```
ports:
      - '8081:8081'
```

on the **index.html** you must update the  **script src path**

From  *< script type="module" src="/src/main.js" >*

To    **< script type="module" src="https://localhost:8081/src/main.js" >**

Answer (score -2):

I had the exactly same problem
the documentation say that there are more options of proxy on https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy#options

https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-proxy

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.